# A question about isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime and let $\Bbb Z(p)$ be the ring of integers mod $p$. Define a function $f:\Bbb Z(p)\to \Bbb Z(p)$ by $$f(a)=\begin{cases}0,  &a=0\\ a^{-1},&a \ne0\end{cases}$$ 
Find all primes $p$ for which $f$ is a ring isomorphism.

I have checked that $f$ is a homomorphism, and it is surjective obvious. But I don't know how to find $p$ to make it injective.

Comment: The problematic part is the homomorphism condition. Generally, you don't have $(a+b)^{-1} = a^{-1} + b^{-1}$.

Comment: $(a+b)^{-1}$ is the inverse of (a+b) under addition or multiplication?

Comment: Multiplication, the inverse for addition is usually denoted $-a$.

Comment: $-(a+b)$ is the additive inverse, $(a+b)^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse. Just like in the rational numbers.

Comment: a=b=1 should be interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only occurs for $p = 2, 3$. If $p > 2$, then for $a \neq 0$, $2(a^{-1}) = 2f(a) = f(2a) = (a+a)^{-1} = (2a)^{-1}$, so $4a = a$, i.e. $3a = 0$ for all $a \neq 0$, so the characteristic must divide $3$.

One can also check that for $p = 2, 3$, $f = \text{id}$.

Comment: why $2f(a)=f(2a)$?

Comment: $f$ is a ring homomorphism, in particular it preserves addition: $f(2a) = f(a + a) = f(a) + f(a) = 2f(a)$

Comment: You're welcome! If you find this answer helpful, please mark it as answered, to avoid staying in the unanswered queue